# Sharepoint : getting a default view for groups

Tags: list, web-part, view, sharepoint-calendar, spsecurity

I have an issue and I don’t know if it’s about getting a default view for our users or about security.

We have a sharepoint calendar at my organiztion. I might say its not really a calendar, it's a list that has certain columns and i created a calendar view for that list so users can see it as a calendar.

Users can add events to the calendar in order to reserve certain rooms for events.

I have a list that contains several groups. Each group has an equivalent security group that has the same name.

I have a calendar where people from these groups can book a room for an event.

I have a page where people can view today, passed, and upcoming events

I want to filter a view on this page to display today, passed and upcoming events but only events, or rooms booked or submitted by their own groups. So users will only see the items created by their own groups or the current user.
What the best way to do that?

Comment: Just to clarify, is the list of groups a column in your calendar list or is it an actual (separate) LIST? Also, should users see ONLY events relevant to their group and nothing else or should they only see their group's events by default but still have permission to see the events of other groups if they look for them?

Comment: I dont have a group column in the calendar list its in a separate list! Users should see only events relevent to their group and nothing else

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use Target Audiences to show different calendars with different default views, but I don't know if that is the best solution

Comment: That would be great if i had only a few groups but i have a huge list of groups (25 ). which means i should creat 25 differents view then find a way to creat a webpage to add a webpart with these views. I wanted to know if there wasn't a better way to do this

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix that with a workflow. i created a column name Group with type Group/person
then i created a workflow thats set the value or the column Group with the value of my listname